# Android Remote Procedure Call

Tags: android, rmi, rpc

I want to create an application for my final year Engineering project wherein I'm trying to take an image on an Android Device and then to pass the Image as a parameter to a remote PC. At the remote PC, I'll be doing image processing (Using Java). Since RMI package hasn't been implemented in Android I'm not sure on how to implement Remote Procedure Call.

My searches landed me with these 2 links:

1. http://blog.pastelstudios.com/2012/10/11/poor-mans-rmi-android-java/
2. https://code.google.com/p/android-json-rpc/

Me, still being a newbie to Android programming can't quite figure out how it's implemented. I'm hoping somebody can explain how I can go about implementing this... If the links I found are my best bet, then maybe somebody could explain on how I can use it for my project.

Any help would be deeply deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to implement a web service rather than an RPC or RMI.  RPC and RMI are styles of programming interface, and for a simple service like you describe are an unnecessary source of complexity.  Encode your image to a standard format (either JPEG or PNG depending on whether you need pixel precision), post it to a Servlet running in a web server (e.g. Apache Tomcat) on your PC and process it, then reencode it and send it back.